# How to get input value from one jsp page to another jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get a one-page input value to another page while clicking the order button.[image]

while I will take a number of item value and click the order button, it will carry the value the order page. The page code is here,

```
<td><%=rs.getString("product_price")%></td>
<td> <input type="number" name="no_item" value="1" /></td>
<td class="text-center" width="250">
 <a href='order.jsp?u=<%=rs.getString("id")%>' class="btn btn-success">Order</a>
 <a href='edit.jsp?u=<%=rs.getString("id")%>' class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
 <a href='delete.jsp?d=<%=rs.getString("id")%>' class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
 </td>
```

The order page code is here,

```
 <%
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    String u=request.getParameter("u");
                    String item_num =request.getParameter("no_item");
                    int num=Integer.parseInt(u);
                    String Data = "select * from products_tbl where id='"+num+"'";
                    rs = statement.executeQuery(Data);
                    String product_price;
                    while (rs.next()) {
                    %>   
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value='<%=rs.getString("id")%>'/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h4 style="float:left; padding-right:8px;">Product Name:</h4> <h4> <%=rs.getString("product_name")%> </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <% 
                     product_price = rs.getString("product_price");  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(product_price); %>
                    </div>
                        <%= item_num %>
                        <%= num1 %>

                    <%   
                    }

                    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of order button add the input value in url query string. you have need to use java script in jsp page.

```
 <script>
 function order(page, id){
     input_value = document.getElementById('no_item').value;
     location.href= page+"?u="+id+"&no_item="+input_value;

 }
 </script>
```

Add the onclick function within order button.

```
<a onclick="order('order.jsp', '<%=rs.getString("id")%>')" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>
```

In order.jsp page you will get the input value.

```
request.getParameter("no_item");
```